# How to make streaming change the text entered in the input with Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encryption

There is a task to implement encryption of text. That is, in one field I enter the text I want to encrypt, and in the second, after pressing the button, output ciphertext. But it is not so interesting and I decided to make the encryption "in real time". It is necessary that I have introduced only one character in the first field and then they had brought the code of the character in another. I know that there are such things in angular as ng-model and ng-bind, may need to write some function to process ng-bind?
`<textarea ng-bind="model.crypt()"></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a filter, e.g.

http://plnkr.co/edit/KuqvWoPy3hGOdXCIxMyQ?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.inputText = '';
});

app.filter('cipher', function() {
  return function(input) {
    // Instead of wrapping in <ciphered> it does the cipher transform
    return '<ciphered>' + input + '</ciphered>';
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input ng-model="inputText">
  <p>output: {{inputText | cipher }}</p>
</body>
```

You could alternatively use a function on the controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.inputText = '';
  $scope.toCipher = function(someInput) {
    return '<fn_ciphered>' + someInput + '</fn_ciphered>';
  }
});
```

And template:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input ng-model="inputText">
  <p>output using function: <span ng-bind="toCipher(inputText)"></span></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive to achieve this. In the input the directive must be inserted:

```
<input encryp ng-model="model.input">
```

And the directive skeleton would be like this:

```
myApp.directive('encryp', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  
          scope.$watch(iAttrs.ngModel, function(value) {
                if (!value) {
                    return;
                }
                //Your encrypter function (if it's in $scope controller)
                var encryp_value = scope.encryp(value);

                controller.$setViewValue(encryp_value);
                controller.$render();

            });
        }
    };
});
```

You can find a little example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jL9jKpbETaND2WzcMlg0?p=preview

In this example my encryp function transform every character to `'*'`

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {input: ''};
  $scope.encryp = function(someInput) {
    var res = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < someInput.length; i++) {
      res += '*';
    }
    return res;
  }
});
```